# AndroidX MultiDex not found

Tags: android, android-multidex, androidx

I'm creating a new android project and decided to use the new AndroidX replacement for the support libraries, docs for which can be found here: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate.

I followed the steps to the letter and after syncing gradle I have access to the `androidx` namespace and various classes contained within. However, when creating my application class I want to inherit from `androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication` (which can be seen in the table in the link above). However, the entire `multidex` package doesn't exist.

Has anyone resolved this issue? Any pointers?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`android.enableJetifier=true` does not make the least sense, *while being able to replace it*.

you can simply add it as a dependency, without non-transparent mangling of name-spaces:

```
implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"
```

Comment: Yea, same as my answer

Comment: @ThomasCook definitely not the same.

Comment: When set to true, the Android plugin automatically migrates existing third-party libraries to use AndroidX by rewriting their binaries. The flag is false by default if it is not specified.

Comment: @ThomasCook it reads "third-party libraries" ...these are basically libraries built against the previous support libraries, where one has no chance to change the dependencies - which isn't the case here.

Answer (score 12):

If you are using androidx you should add MultiDexApplication(**reference from androidx**) to your manifest file.

```
<application
        android:name="androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
        .....></application>
```

Comment: Why this "name" is not in official documentation?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Martin Zeitler's answer, I had to add in my gradle build file:

```
defaultConfig {
  ...
  multiDexEnabled true // Add this line
  ...
}
```

As well as the dependency

```
implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0"
```

As to why it happens, [this userguide](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex) on Android Developers explains it very well.

Answer (score 2):

```
build.gradle app module 

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

         defaultConfig {
             minSdkVersion 14 //lower than 14 doesn't support multidex
             targetSdkVersion 22

             // Enabling multidex support.
             multiDexEnabled true
         }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for androidX. Please refer other answer.

Comment: @ggDeGreat use this dependency `implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'`

Answer (score 1):

Ok, figured it out!

Multidex library was never part of android support lib, it was additional library that had to be imported in gradle. So, I've now imported it in my dependencies block in my modules gradle file and set the following in my gradle.properties file:

```
# Jetifier automatically updates dependancy binaries
# To swap out support lib for androix
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Now, at compile time, the multidex dependency is swapped out for androidx implementation.